# Button is not responding in Android when I scale or move my Custom RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, zooming, android-relativelayout

I was working with the `Custom RelativeLayout` because I want to zoom scale and rotate whatever views present in that layout.
These features are working correctly but the problem is when I insert the button in layout and move the layout on screen the button doesn't respond but the position where it was originally or initially located responds.
Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong.
Please help.

Here is `Custom RelativeLayout Code`:

```
public class ZoomableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements
        OnTouchListener {

//  float mScaleFactor = 1;
    float mPivotX;
    float mPivotY;

    /*
     * New Declarations
     */
     private float mScaleFactor = 0.6f;
    private float mRotationDegrees = 0.f;
    private float changeInRotationDegrees;
    private float mFocusX;
    private float mFocusY;
    private  float layoutCenterX, layoutCenterY;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(
            getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    private RotateGestureDetector mRotateDetector = new RotateGestureDetector(
            getContext(), new RotateListener());
    private MoveGestureDetector mMoveDetector = new MoveGestureDetector(
            getContext(), new MoveListener());
    private boolean firstTym = true;

    // private ShoveGestureDetector mShoveDetector;
    /*
     * End of New Declarations
     */

    public ZoomableRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        // setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public ZoomableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setOnTouchListener(this);

        MyMainActivity mContext = (MyMainActivity) context;
        Display defaultDisplay = mContext.getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        mFocusX = defaultDisplay.getWidth() / 2f;
        mFocusY = defaultDisplay.getHeight() / 2f;


    }

    public ZoomableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        // setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (firstTym) {
            layoutCenterX = (getWidth() * mScaleFactor) / 2;
            layoutCenterY = (getHeight() * mScaleFactor) / 2;
//          Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+layoutCenterX+"***"+layoutCenterY, 2000).show();
            firstTym = false;
        }

        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.rotate(mRotationDegrees, layoutCenterX,layoutCenterY);
        canvas.translate((mFocusX - layoutCenterX), (mFocusY - layoutCenterY));


        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            layoutCenterX = (v.getWidth() * mScaleFactor) / 2;
            layoutCenterY = (v.getHeight() * mScaleFactor) / 2;

            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            mRotateDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            mMoveDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {


            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor(); // scale change since
                                                        // previous event
            ZoomableRelativeLayout.this.invalidate();
            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
//          mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            return true;
        }
    }

    private class RotateListener extends
            RotateGestureDetector.SimpleOnRotateGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector) {


            mRotationDegrees -= detector.getRotationDegreesDelta();
            ZoomableRelativeLayout.this.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class MoveListener extends
            MoveGestureDetector.SimpleOnMoveGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(MoveGestureDetector detector) {
            PointF d = detector.getFocusDelta();
            mFocusX += d.x;
            mFocusY += d.y;

            ZoomableRelativeLayout.this.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning `true` on the overriden `onTouch` method, it means that the event won't go deeper in your view hierarchy, and therefore it will never hit the button. Try to give the MotionEvent directly to the button:
(you must reference it in your `ZoomableRelativeLayout` first)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        layoutCenterX = (v.getWidth() * mScaleFactor) / 2;
        layoutCenterY = (v.getHeight() * mScaleFactor) / 2;

        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        mRotateDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        mMoveDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        myButton.onTouch(event);

        return true;
}

Button myButton;

public void setMyButton(Button b) {
    this.myButton = b;
}
```

Comment: How can I get the Button in the ZoomableRelativeLayout class. Its reference is in the MainActivity.

Comment: create a simple setter